# Why revision number in version control does not increase by 1 all the time?

Tags: svn, version-control

When I use "svn log", for example, to view the revision history, I find that the revision number does not increase one by one all the time. For example, one revision has revision number "1234" but its next revision has revision number "1256" instead of "1235". What happens between these two revisions? What their revision numbers are not consecutive?

Thanks.

Comment: If you fetch the SVN log for the entire repository, you will find that SVN does indeed grow the version number by one for each commit, but that includes commits to different branches and different projects in the same repository.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your project within the SVN repo might not be the only one.
Any revision in any part of the SVN repo will increment the *global* revision  number by one.
See also:

- "[How increment in revision number calculated in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265214/how-increment-in-revision-number-calculated-in-subversion#comment10173995_8265259)".
- "[Subversion revision number across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674/subversion-revision-number-across-multiple-projects)"

Answer (score 3):

If you get the log from the root of your repository, you will see that the revision number is incremented one by one. BUT, you are getting the log from a sub-directory of your repo. This means that there are lots of revisions that does not belong to your sub-directory.